# Django: UserAuthentication | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'userAuthentication'

Tags: django

I've been trying to create a user login and logout with django's bulid-in authenticated views.
I changed the project-level URL pattern

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/',include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('', include('home.urls')),
   
]
```

[added template registration/login.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8eFA.png)

and updated LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL in settings.py

but still getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'userAuthentication'.I don't know if I am missing anything in these it would be appreciated if anyone can give the heads up.

note: I was trying to recreate exactly this

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views

[Installed Apps and middleware in settings.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HVgp.png)

Comment: Hi, can you show us your `INSTALLED_APPS` from `settings.py`?

Comment: **@lucutzu33** i have edited and attached img of `INSTALLED_APPS` above

Comment: Try to remove the line starting with `userAuthentication` in `INSTALLED_APPS`. That's what's causing the error.